# JS regex find replace URL's protocol and from a string to end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

For example, i have these strings:

> https://variant-color.com
>
> http://variant-size.biz
>
> http://variant-type.ca

I want to remove the URL's protocol, `variant-`, and domain using JS `.replace()` and regex, so the strings will be:

> color
>
> size
>
> type

How to do it? I've tried it with the following code but it didn't work:

`.replace("http://variant-","").replace("https://variant-","").replace(/^.[a-zA-Z]*/,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are multiple ways to do this. One of the easiest one could be using [positive look behind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) approach with this regex:

```
/(?<=\-)\w+/gm
```

This will only match characters in your URL once they followed by `-` sign.

So the final output will be something like this:

```js
const arr = [
  "https://variant-color.com",
  "http://variant-size.biz",
  "http://variant-type.ca"
]

const newArr = arr.flatMap(item => {
  return item.match(/(?<=\-)\w+/gm)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Thanks its work, but is there any similar method if we use jQuery?

Comment: @OzikJarwo I'm not sure what do you mean by *jQuery* here. But [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is available through every javascript library.